# Why I can not making another layout unit into layout unit

Tags: jsf, primefaces

this is my code but when I remove the layout inside the layout unite it works fine

```
<p:layout style="width:850px;height:300px;" id="layout">  
  <p:layoutUnit position="west" resizable="true" size="230" minSize="40" maxSize="200" >  
               <center>
             <p:graphicImage  value="/resources/image/miseAjour.jpg" />
               </center> 
  </p:layoutUnit>

 <p:layoutUnit position="center" header="Composant">
    /*I wont to compose this layout 
    <p:layoutUnit position="center" header="element">  
                   </p:layoutUnit>

                   <p:layoutUnit position="south" header="definiton">
                   </p:layoutUnit>
    </p:layoutUnit> 

</p:layout>
```

Comment: You'll have to be more specific - what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to surround the nested layout in a `<p:layout>` tag....so:

```
    <p:layout style="width:850px;height:300px;" id="layout">  
      <p:layoutUnit position="west" resizable="true" size="230" minSize="40" maxSize="200" >  

                 <p:graphicImage  value="/resources/image/miseAjour.jpg" />

      </p:layoutUnit>

     <p:layoutUnit position="center" header="Composant">
     //nested layout
        <p:layout>
        <p:layoutUnit position="center" header="element">  
                       </p:layoutUnit>

                       <p:layoutUnit position="south" header="definiton">
                       </p:layoutUnit>
    </p:layout>
    //end of nested layout
        </p:layoutUnit> 

    </p:layout>
```

Comment: not sure why there is a miscellaneous <center> tag in the markup

Comment: The code above works for me so it is supported in Primefaces 3.5 which I'm using. Make sure you get rid of the <center> tag that you've put in your markup - it's not valid. What errors are you actually getting? Please try copying and pasting my code into a blank xhtml page with just an h:form

Comment: thank you it is working know like your code ,,I don't kwonw whay center making problem .I just wont to make igmage in the midel

Comment: You can align the image using css. Assign a styleClass to the image tag and use css to align it.